# Microsoft Visual Studio - HTML and CSS export

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

it may seem as a dumb question, but I started using VS for HTML and CSS coding I can't seem to find how to export my project. I found help on Microsoft Developer Centre or what and I just can't find it. Can you give me a better explaination?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more clarification on what you mean by exporting the project?   Need access the project directory? Just right click the project in solution explorer and view in Explorer.

Comment: try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) it's more for HTML +CSS than the regular VS although you write HTML + CSS there too

Comment: What do you mean "export my project"? Export to what, a zip? Just navigate to the folder on disk and you can zip all your files from windows explorer

Comment: I mean like it saves those files in some kind format that only VS can recognise, or not? And I want to export it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use another code editor for `html` `css`,like notepad ++ , sublime text and so on, visualstudio focused on .net apps .

Visual Studio doesn't export your code , for .net apps it will debug and build your app with needed files also you can use `save all as` option from `file` menu to select where to save your files

Answer (score 0):

For exporting your project in vs Studio you should:
Right click on your project then Select Export Program.
Under Export toolchain, select Visual Studio Code
Click Export, and unpack at a convenient location.